# How does Lucifer kill these creatures?

Tags: supernatural

In the episode "The End"

> when Dean is zapped into the future all the Angels are missing. In the episode "I believe children are our future" they find the Anti-Christ and Castiel says something like "With one thought destroy heaven" or something like that.

Anyway

> is this what happened in that episode "The End"... as in all the Angels were killed by this kid.. or is there another explanation I do not know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [transcript](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=5.04_The_End_%28transcript%29) of the episode in question, angels were not killed, they just left. Unfortunately I don't think it has been explained how and where they went.

Conversation between Dean and 2014 Dean about saying **Yes** to Michael:

> *2014!DEAN*
>
> Look around you, man. Half the planet's better than no planet, which
>   is what we have now. If I could do it over again, I'd say 'yes' in a
>   heartbeat.
>
> *DEAN*
>
> So why don't you?
>
> *2014!DEAN*
>
> I've tried! I've shouted 'yes' till I was blue in the face!
>   **The angels aren't listening! They just—left—gave up!** It's too late for
>   me, but for you—
>
> *DEAN*
>
> Oh, no. There's got to be another way.

Dean talking to 2014 Castiel:

> *2014!CASTIEL*
>
> Yeah, I went mortal.
>
> *DEAN*
>
> What do you mean? How?
>
> *2014!CASTIEL*
>
> **I think it had something to do with the other angels leaving.** 
>   But when they bailed, my mojo just kind of— psshhew!—drained
>   away. And now, you know, I'm practically human. I mean, Dean, I'm all
>   but useless. Last year, broke my foot, laid up for two months.

Comment: So you are saying that they were not "destroyed" by this Anti-Christ thing? They just left? I mean, those transcripts seam to me to be that the characters do not know, form their perspective they just "left".. but there seams to be no explanation for why, or how that happened. I am not sure I am seeing anything here to counter the supposition that Lucifer gains control of the Anti-Christ and used him to destroy heaven, and possibly all the angels and that is why from Dean's / Castiel's perspective they just "disappeared"?

Comment: @aJynks I'm not saying no to your theory, but I would assume that Castiel, being an angel, would sense something as big as destruction of heaven and extermination of angels. Kind of a 'I sense great disturbance in the force' situation :)

Comment: I get what your saying, and I appreciate the time you took to reply. If no one adds anything I'll mark as answered, but I was hoping that there could be something more here, maybe from another user.